# How to execute job dsl script in Jenkins workflow (pipeline) plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to combine nice branching handling of Workflow [Multibranch](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin)
 with powerfull [Job-Dsl](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workflow+Plugin) plugin Job generation. So basically I want branch to regenerate it's jobs from script in repository and run the main one.

But I don't see a way to run `Process Job DSLs` step from workflow script. May be there is a built in way to execute custom steps in Workflow, but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a separate job that processes the job-dsl, and then call it with the proper parameters from the workflow via a "build job: xxx" step.

Comment: Yes, in seems to be the only option. But Workflow does not expose a variables like WORKSPACE or GIT_COMMIT and retrieving those manually looks like a hack...

Comment: also it didn't work for me - there were various strangeproblems with executing job-dsl script from a workflow job, basically that that's the only way I've come to.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure where you are going with this, but perhaps what you really want is multibranch binding for Job DSL, or to manually iterate branches.

Alternately, with Workflow alone you can probably accomplish your goal, whatever that is.

Comment: Well what I really need is a normal support for branches in Jenkins like in other CI solutions, I used to work with :) Workflow is a nice plugin, but comparing to Job DSL it has like 10% of it's functionality, and one can say, they are even orthogonal in their purposes. The goal is to setup complex workflows, that are generated from source control, differ from branch to branch, and are still customizable through UI to some extent. Multibranch binding - you mean multibranch plugin? If yes, it does not provide a way not to checkout branches based on there contents, like workflow with Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the jobDSL method can be used in the pipeline.

Have a look into the Snippet Generator to generate some code :
[image]